# Get audio from both front and back connectors eOS Juno

Tags: release-juno, sound

I'm new to Elementary and Linux in general, my question is if its possible to have audio from both frontal and back audio jacks at the same time.

Example, I have coneccted my headphones to the back panel and my main audio speakers to the front pannel. 
In windows I get sound from both at the same time, so when I want to listen to music I just turn on the speakers, the pc keeps sending sound for both connectors.

Is there a way to do this in Elementary OS?

PD: I didnt do anything to achieve this on windows, just plugged and it worked, so it isnt an specific function or a program.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it, just installed pavucontrol, and changed the audio output to analog headset, it reads unplugged, but it worked like a charm.

Comment: it could not be done from system sound settings?